# different .env and config files on same laravel application

Tags: laravel, localization, internationalization, laravel-5.3

I have runing laravel application that now needs internationalization.
We translated all strings for lang files. Problem is that we have lot of strings in DB (noone expected we will need to translate something like STATUS name).
Above that, there will be some specific blade files for each country (invoice layout) also some specific settings (like VAT).

I'm thinking of installing different databases for each country.

My question is, is there any way i could use same "engine", and have different .env (db info) and maybe config/app file (need different default locale)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off keeping it in one DB. Multiple DBs will make it hard to maintain.

Set the language when the user logs in and then store it in the session. Use this when you display your views.

Alternatively You can set the database on the fly if you want, I think I did something like this https://lukevers.com/2015/03/25/on-the-fly-database-connections-with-laravel-5 This mean you can store you database details where you want.